# How to filter objects returned by ObjectDataSource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datasource, objectdatasource

I have a `DropDownList`, that loads data from an `ObjectDataSource` which returns `ArrayList<MyObject>`. I would like to know, how to filter the returned `ArrayList`.

For example, one of the properties of `MyObject` class is 'IsCompulsory'. Once the ODS loads `ArrayList<MyObject>` and before data binding it to the `DropDownList`, I would like to remove all the objects where `IsCompulsory = false`.

How do I do that? I thought `ObjectDataSource`'s `OnSelected` event is a good place, but how do I filter the values & how should I return it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the OnSelected method may be too late to filter the data. Another approach could be to use `Parameters` on the ObjectDataSource in order to query only the data you need. This could actually improve performance. You can either set them declaratively or programmatically.

Here is an example (see link below for a complete example):

```
<asp:objectdatasource
  ID="ObjectDataSource1"
  runat="server"
  SelectMethod="GetMyObject"
  TypeName="MyNamespace.MyClass" >
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="CheckBox1" DefaultValue="false" Name="myCondition" />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:objectdatasource>
```

Complete example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57hkzhy5.aspx

Comment: I am aware of that approach. In my case I gotta use the same API in a few places and I have to filter the returned data before binding it to my controls.

Comment: Mmm I'm not sure if you can accomplish what you need without modifying your API and still using the ObjectDataSource control. I'm curious as to what others have to say on this one.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `LINQ` to do that, as shown below :

```
 List<MyObject> filteredObjects = (from MyObject obj in sourceObjects
                                          where obj.IsCompulsory == false
                                          select obj).ToList<MyObject>();
```

Assuming that you have your list(to be filtered) in `sourceObjects`.

P.S. Do not forget to add `using System.Linq;` for above to work properly.

**EDIT :** You need to use `filteredObjects` as `DataSource` for your `DropDownList` now.

Comment: Right. I know how to filter data. Trying to know where to do that. It gotta be in some event of `asp:ObjectDataSource`. It could be `OnSelected`, not sure, and dont know how to return the filter data.